# Segmentation fault (core dumped) при realloc

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Пояснение: все это счастье компилируется в библиотеку расширения PHP

Структуры

```
typedef struct {
    char *class_name;
    char *name;
    int size;
    int capacity;
    op_dumper_node *op_codes;
} op_dumper_function;

typedef struct {
    char *name;
    int size;
    int capacity;
    op_dumper_function *functions;
} op_dumper_file;

typedef struct {
    int size;
    int capacity;
    op_dumper_file *files;
} op_dumper_result;

op_dumper_result *result_data;
```

Собственно пытаюсь сделать наивную реализацию динамического массива

Для расширения `result_data->files` использую вот такой код. Отлично работает.

```
if (result_data->size == result_data->capacity) {
    result_data->capacity *= 2;
    result_data->files = realloc(result_data->files, sizeof(op_dumper_file) * result_data->capacity);
}
```

Для расширения `result_data->files[index].functions` вот такой:

```
if (result_data->files[file_num].size == result_data->files[file_num].capacity){
    op_dumper_file *file = &result_data->files[file_num];
    file->capacity *=2;
    file->functions = realloc(
            file->functions,
            sizeof(op_dumper_function) * file->capacity
    );
}
```

Отрабатывает, но, в последствии, приводит к ошибке:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Да, именно этот кусок кода приводит к ошибке. Если условие не отрабатывает, то падения нет.

Падает, насколько я понял, уже сам PHP.

Где я не прав?

*UPD* Причем падает даже если реально в добавленный кусок ничего не записывалось
Т.е. 
1) пишем 3 элемента в массив из 3-х элементов - все ок.
2) пишем 3 элемента в массив из 3-х элементов, потом перевыделяем память под 6 элементов, но реально больше их не добавляем - падение.

Comment: А ```gdb``` что показывает? Не смотрели?

Comment: @misdeed я в C совсем чайник. Таких штук пока еще не знаю. Надеялся, что для знатоков косяк в коде будет очевиден :)

Comment: У вас линукс или венда?

Comment: @misdeed линукс

Comment: можете поставить radare2?

Comment: @misdeed знать бы что это. Но скорее всего нет, так как не админ там

Comment: @ ну, тогда ```man gdb```, и ищите, в какой строке падает программа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начитавшись интернета поменял следующим образом:

```
typedef struct {
    char *class_name;
    char *name;
    int size;
    int capacity;
    op_dumper_node **op_codes;   <-------------------
} op_dumper_function;

typedef struct {
    char *name;
    int size;
    int capacity;
    op_dumper_function **functions;    <-------------------
} op_dumper_file;

typedef struct {
    int size;
    int capacity;
    op_dumper_file **files;    <-------------------
} op_dumper_result;
```

И аккуратное, последовательное, разыменовывание указателей

```
op_dumper_file *file = &result_data->files[file_num];
op_dumper_function *function = &file->functions[file->size];
```

PS Ошибка была не в realloc, а в неправильном подходе в принципе

Comment: В вызове *realloc* у вас всё ещё неточность, нельзя присваивать сразу результат в ту же переменную, которая была указана в параметрах.

Comment: Смысла менять на двойной указатель нет никакого. Тем более к вам там реально не указатели на указатель, в массивы, если я правильно понял.

Comment: Выделение памяти степенной функцией не очень хорошо, попробуйте лучше ряд Фибоначчи.